# Get Object value with specific key

Tags: java

I have a ObservableMap from which I would like to get all values which start with the key "CPU":

```
ObservableMap<Object, Object> properties
```

I tried this code:

```
ObservableMap<Object, Object> properties = children.getProperties();

                        for (int i = 0; i < properties.size(); i++)
                        {

                            if (properties.equals("CPU"))
                            {

                                children.setVisible(true);
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                children.setVisible(false);
                            }

                        }
```

But the code is not working properly. Can you help me to fix the code?

Comment: You are not looking at the keys, you are checking if the entire map is equal to "CPU"

Comment: @chancea can you show me how to do this because I don't know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that keys in the Map are Strings then either declare the Map as `ObservableMap<String, Object>` or cast each key to a String before invoking equals.

```
ObservableMap<Object, Object> properties = children.getProperties();
    for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
        String key = (String) entry.getKey();
        if (key.equals("CPU")) {
            children.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            children.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `key.equals("CPU")` checks for exact match, but OP asked for starts with "CPU"

Comment: What about `children.setVisible(properties.containsKey("CPU"));`?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing if the `ObservableMap<Object, Object>` is equal to a string `"CPU"`.

Next, if continue with comparing the key object in your map, which by the way, is of type `Object` the `equals` method will check if the objects you are comparing are the same object in memory.

I could make a loose guess that the keys can be cast to `String`, so before comparing them to `"CPU"`, cast them to strings so that you will utilize the overriden `equals` method.

Comment: see nomis' answer. Also read up on the `equals` method and how/why it's important to know what your object actually is.